# Why is Mongodb returning an object, then returning null without any changes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to make a simple Blog Website that stores the posts, I have them in a mongodb database with just two attributes, the title and the content.  My problem is when I try to access a custom route parameter where the custom parameter is the title of the post, I am able to find the object and render the page but then the app crashes, and I can no longer navigate throughout the website.

Here's the function in question:

```
 app.get("/:day", async function(req,res){
    let customPost = await blogPost.findOne({title : req.params.day})
    console.log(customPost)
    res.render("postTemplate", {dayNumber : customPost.title, postText : customPost.content})
 })
```

And here's the output:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("645af28168fe4384c8792cd1"),
  title: 'efawefawe',
  content: 'fseaweawelj',
  __v: 0
}
null
D:\Microsoft VS Code\Web Development Projects\Blog Website\index.js:57
    res.render("postTemplate", {dayNumber : customPost.title, postText : customPost.content})
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')
    at D:\Microsoft VS Code\Web Development Projects\Blog Website\index.js:57:56
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v19.8.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't understand why the object is found and logged, then null is logged, and then the app crashes I guess because it can't read the properties of customPost. The EJS Template renders the post fine after a couple seconds, but then I can't go anywhere else on the website. Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you debug how many requests hit this route? And check the `req.params` using `console.log(req.params.day)`.

Comment: From earlier tests it looks like 3 requests hit this route, and when I log the request parameters is does indeed log the title, in the case above it would be that random text efawefawe, though it does also log index.js. I put the console.log(req.params.day) as the first thing in the function and it logs the title first, then the object like I posted above, then index.js.